# IPackageStatsObserver cannot be resolved to a type (Android)

Tags: java, android, sdk

I want to calculate the sum of all the cache memory utilizing the device. For this I am getting a compiled time error:

```
IPackageStatsObserver cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have mentioned this error 2 times in the code:

```
public long totalCacheSize(){
    totalSize=0;

    PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

     /* List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager
      .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);*/
     // PackageManager.GET_META_DATA

    List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager
            .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {

        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

        Method getPackageSizeInfo;
        try {
            getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass()
                    .getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo",
                        String.class, Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageStatsObserver"));

            getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, p.packageName,
                    new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() { //error

                        public void onGetStatsCompleted(
                                PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                                throws RemoteException {

                            totalSize = totalSize + pStats.cacheSize;
                            Log.d("size", totalSize+"");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass()
                        .getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo",
                            String.class, Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageStatsObserver"));

                getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, p.packageName,
                        new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() { //error

                            public void onGetStatsCompleted(
                                    PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                                    throws RemoteException {

                                totalSize = totalSize + pStats.cacheSize;
                                Log.d("size", totalSize+"");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.d("eeeeeeeeeee", "error");
                ee.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } 
    }

    Log.d("return size", totalSize+"");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "return size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return totalSize;
}
```

`IPackageStatsObserver` is not available in android SDK. Perhaps loading the Stub class using `Class.forName()`, finding the default constructor and invoke it to get a new instance of a `Stub`. But what should I code it, I do not know anything about it!?

Help !!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To resolve your issue follow these steps:

**Android Studio**

- Right click on your project **New > Folder > AIDL Folder**
- Press **Finish**
- Right click on `aidl` folder **New > Package**
- Insert `android.content.pm` and press **OK**
- Download [IPackageStatsObserver.aidl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/master/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver.aidl)
- Copy the aidl file inside the `android.content.pm` package
- **Build > Rebuild Project**

**Eclipse**

- Right click on `src` folder **New > Package**
- Insert `android.content.pm`
- Press **Finish**
- Download [IPackageStatsObserver.aidl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/master/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver.aidl)
- Copy the aidl file inside the `android.content.pm` package
- Select class where `totalCacheSize` is then **Source > Organize Imports**

Answer (score 1):

you need to add [IPackageStatsObserver.aidl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver.aidl) and [PackageStats.aidl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageStats.aidl) in your project.

Comment: I tried using their code  getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, "com.android.mms", new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() { //error
            still the same error

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

From Android O (API level 26) you can not use `getPackageSizeInfo` method with reflaction. Following post includes a code that can help you for both apps below api level 26 and above it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616172/1939409

Answer (score 0):

follow steps below

```
app > src > main >java >
```

in this path create three folders

```
create folder =  "android"> "content" > "pm"
```

in pm folder paste this file for retrieving all system caches

IPackageDataObserver.java

```
 package android.content.pm;

import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.IInterface;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.RemoteException;

public interface IPackageDataObserver extends IInterface {

public static abstract class Stub extends Binder implements IPackageDataObserver {
    private static final String DESCRIPTOR = "android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver";
    static final int TRANSACTION_onRemoveCompleted = 1;

    private static class Proxy implements IPackageDataObserver {
        private IBinder mRemote;

        public String getInterfaceDescriptor() {
            return Stub.DESCRIPTOR;
        }

        Proxy(IBinder iBinder) {
            this.mRemote = iBinder;
        }

        public IBinder asBinder() {
            return this.mRemote;
        }

        public void onRemoveCompleted(String str, boolean z) throws RemoteException {
            Parcel obtain = Parcel.obtain();
            try {
                obtain.writeInterfaceToken(Stub.DESCRIPTOR);
                obtain.writeString(str);
                obtain.writeInt(z ? 1 : 0);
                this.mRemote.transact(1, obtain, null, 1);
            } finally {
                obtain.recycle();
            }
        }
    }

    public IBinder asBinder() {
        return this;
    }

    public Stub() {
        attachInterface(this, DESCRIPTOR);
    }

    public static IPackageDataObserver asInterface(IBinder iBinder) {
        if (iBinder == null) {
            return null;
        }
        IInterface queryLocalInterface = iBinder.queryLocalInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
        if (queryLocalInterface == null || !(queryLocalInterface instanceof IPackageDataObserver)) {
            return new Proxy(iBinder);
        }
        return (IPackageDataObserver) queryLocalInterface;
    }

    public boolean onTransact(int i, Parcel parcel, Parcel parcel2, int i2) throws RemoteException {
        String str = DESCRIPTOR;
        if (i == 1) {
            parcel.enforceInterface(str);
            onRemoveCompleted(parcel.readString(), parcel.readInt() != 0);
            return true;
        } else if (i != 1598968902) {
            return super.onTransact(i, parcel, parcel2, i2);
        } else {
            parcel2.writeString(str);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

void onRemoveCompleted(String str, boolean z) throws RemoteException;
}
```