# How to get size of an App + size of Data of the App

Tags: java, android, size

How can I get the size of an app, including the size of the AppData?

At the moment I use this code, but it just gets the APK size. Is there any way to get the size of the AppData, like the Google Setting App does it?

```
public String getApkSize(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        float value = new File(context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).publicSourceDir).length() / 1048576F;

        if (value <= 0) {
            value = 1;
        }

        return String.format("%.2f", value) + "MB";
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Settings app uses the method [`getPackageSizeInfo`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#4118). Unfortunately this method is hidden because it is annotated with `@hide`, for this reason you can't directly use the method, but you need to use reflection to invoke it.

Add this permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE"/>
```

Create the AIDL interface [`IPackageStatsObserver`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver.aidl):

```
package android.content.pm;

import android.content.pm.PackageStats;
/**
 * API for package data change related callbacks from the Package Manager.
 * Some usage scenarios include deletion of cache directory, generate
 * statistics related to code, data, cache usage(TODO)
 * {@hide}
 */
oneway interface IPackageStatsObserver {

    void onGetStatsCompleted(in PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
private void getPackageSizeInfo(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Method getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass().getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

        getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, packageName, new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
            public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats packageStats, boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException {
                long totalCacheSize = packageStats.cacheSize + packageStats.externalCacheSize;
                long totalDataSize = packageStats.dataSize + packageStats.externalDataSize;
                long totalCodeSize = packageStats.codeSize + packageStats.externalCodeSize;
                long totalSize = totalDataSize + totalCodeSize;

                Log.d(TAG, "Total Size:" + totalSize);
                Log.d(TAG, "App Size:" + totalCodeSize);
                Log.d(TAG, "Data Size:" + totalDataSize);
                Log.d(TAG, "Cache Size:" + totalCacheSize);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to add this aidl file I get this : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1    Other aidl files work

Comment: ok got it working referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791461/ipackagestatsobserver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-android

Comment: No, the hidden method that you need to use is `getPackageSizeInfo` so the example is correct.

Comment: OK thank you. It seems like it work with both, is there any reason for that ?

Comment: This is the code of [PackageManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java) and there isn't the method `onGetStatsCompleted`, so it's really strange that it can work for you. I can assure that it doesn't work for me. The only working solution is the one in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no official way to do so. The following relies on reflections so runtime errors could be around the corner.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
    "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.android.mms",
    new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
            throws RemoteException {

            Log.i(TAG, "codeSize: " + pStats.codeSize);
        }
    });
```

Careful since this is a hack trying to fulfill a missing part of the Android SDK.